# SSL for mongodb hosted on private IP

Tags: mongodb, ssl, tls1.3

I have mongodb installed on EC2 instance, I have removed the public IP and DNS and using private IP to connect to DB, is there a way to installed signed SSL certificate (authority) for private IP. I have tested it public DNS but don't want to open the DB/server for public.

Comment: Of course, technically you can put any hostname/IP in the SAN (Subject Alternative Name) of the certificate. But the authority may not permit any value. Or you create your own certificates.

Comment: It will be difficult, if not impossible, to get a public certificate issued for a private IP address. You could self-sign the certificate, but since you're on a private network, do you need a certificate at all?

Comment: What do you mean by "private IP"? A [Private IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) is not routed through the internet, so I doubt that you can connect at all.

Comment: Enable authentication and require SSL, then nobody else than you can access the MongoDB.

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/#configure-mongod-and-mongos-for-tls-ssl  as Wernfried said, you will need to use self-signed certificate and add own CA key to the configs.  There are very few industries that require TLS for private networks.  Don't bother with them unless you you are sure you need it.  It's more secure to use private IP without SSL, than public IP with SSL.